# Валидация datetime на клиенте

Tags: c#, datepicker

В модельке есть поле

```
[DisplayName("Время начала")]
public DateTime? DateTimeStart { get; set; }//начало действия
```

во view отображаю так (использую бутстраповский datetime picker):

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.DateTimeStart, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker-input", @data_target = "#datetimepicker1", @id = "dateTimeStartForPosition", @value = "", @type = "text" } })
```

верный формат только такой: 10-10-2018 12:12:12

как мне указать для валидации другой формат?? т е такой проходит все, кроме валидации модели `10.10.2018 12:12:12`

Comment: [гугол](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24926916/312041)?

Comment: @tym32167 не то....валидация не проходила из-за модели. Собственно ответ нашел...спасибо за уделенное внимание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно в модели указать формат валидации для поля `DateTime` например так:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```